# Como retirar espaços de uma string em C?

Tags: c, string

Eu quero retirar os espaços de uma *string*, exemplo:

```
Pedro Henrique Ribeiro
```

Ficaria:

```
Pedrohenriqueribeiro
```

O código que fiz, retira o espaço, porém duplica uma letra:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv){

    char string[101];
    int x, i, a;

    printf("Foneca uma string com espacos em branco: ");
    gets(string);
    printf("%s\n",string);

    for(i=0; i<strlen(string); i++){
        if(string[i]==' '){
            string[i]=string[i+1];
        }   
    }

    printf("String sem espaços em branco: %s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ao invés de alterar a string que você já tem, gere uma nova, adicionando caractere a caractere. Quando for espaço você pula a inserção ;)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 8):

Seria mais fácil jogar em uma *string* auxiliar, mas se for para fazer isto, precisa controlar separadamente o andamento da leitura de cada caractere e do caractere que deve ser "copiado". Assim toda vez que encontrar um espaço, ele precisa ser ignorado, então o espaço deve incrementar o contador do caractere que deve ser lido de forma definitiva. Do jeito feito, ele incrementa só na hora de pegar, mas os demais caracteres não sentirão o incremento e voltam pegar o caractere errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[101];
    int posicao = 0;
    printf("Forneca uma string com espacos em branco: ");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);//mudei aqui para modernizar. ideone ñ aceita gets
    int len = strlen(string); //só pra dar melhor performance
    printf("%s\n", string);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ') continue;
        string[posicao] = string[i];
        posicao++;
    }
    string[posicao] = '\0'; // coloca o null no fim pra finalizar a string
    printf("String sem espaços em branco: %s\n", string);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BKAsLb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hrulpsdo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/RemoveSpaces.c).

Comment: Exclente! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @PRibeiro Dê uma olha no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta na sua pergunta e votar em qualquer coisa no site.

Answer (score 3):

Caracteres que representam espacos em branco podem ser testados usando a função `isspace()` da biblioteca padrão `ctype.h`.

O segredo é varrer a string de entrada, caracter a caracter, e se o caracter lido for diferente de um espaco em branco, ele será copiado para a string de saida, caso contrário, será ignorado.

Segue código fonte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * remove_espacos( char * out, const char * in )
{
    const char * p = in;
    int i = 0;

    while( *p )
    {
        if( !isspace(*p) )
            out[i++] = *p;

        p++;
    }

    out[i] = 0;

    return out;
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    const char * entrada = "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.";
    char saida[ 100 ] = {0};

    remove_espacos( saida, entrada );

    printf("Entrada: %s\n", entrada );
    printf("Saida: %s\n", saida );

    return 0;
}

/* eof */
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução bem simples seria a do código abaixo , utilizando uma string auxiliar e a biblioteca stdio.h, porem não é a mais optimizada.

```
int main()
{
    int i=0,k=0;
    char str[51],str2[51]="Ola";

fgets(str,51,stdin);

for(;i<51;i++){
    if(str[i]=='\0')break;
    if(str[i]==' ')continue;
    str2[k]=str[i];
    k++;
}

printf("%s",str2);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma função `rmv`, que recebe a String `str` e faz as modificações e faz as modificações na própria variável.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void rmv(char *str){ 
    int count=0,i;
    for(i=0;str[i];i++){
        if(str[i]!=' '){
            str[count++]=str[i];
        }
    }
    str[count]=0;
} 
int main(){ 
    char str[]="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    rmv(str);
    puts(str);
    return 0;
}
```